# How to prove that $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}(x_\nu\partial_\rho-x_\rho\partial_\nu)\partial_\sigma=0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, angular-momentum, tensor-calculus

I would like to prove that $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}(x_\nu\partial_\rho-x_\rho\partial_\nu)\partial_\sigma=0$. But I don't know how to do it. I am also looking for general tricks to prove things "like this".

Here is what I "tried":

We know that $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ is totally antisymmetric. If I choose a given $\mu$, the last terms $\nu \rho \sigma$ in  $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ will still be antisymmetric. So, I noticed that $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ is antisymmetric in $\nu \rho$ and an antisymmetric * symmetric element will give 0 after summation. But $(x_\nu\partial_\rho-x_\rho\partial_\nu)$ is also antisymmetric so it doesn't work. Then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\partial\partial$ is symmetric.

Comment: Aah yeah. I develop $\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}(x_\nu\partial_\rho-x_\rho\partial_\nu)\partial_\sigma=$ in $$\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}x_\nu\partial_\rho\partial_\sigma-\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}x_\rho\partial_\nu\partial_\sigma$$ And each term is antisymmetric * symmetric (the first one in $\rho \sigma$ and the second in $\nu \sigma$) so each term $=0$ And so it works !
Thanks !